# Windows processes making strange outside connections

Tags: windows, networking

I have many processes on windows trying to connect to activate.adobe.com

It's obviously some activation thing, and it's probably legit (although it's already activated)

IF threre is a request, there is a reason, and I'll handle this reason later, but right now, **the big point is:** I don't want the computer pinging stuff on the internet without my consent.

With your help I'd like to learn how to prevent this

The processes are lsass, WmiPrvSE, svchost, and SCNotification.

*Notice that these are system processes, performing something that is not natural/usual to them. As in, they are being COMMANDED to make these connections.*

I'm curious on finding out how to find the trigger for these connections (not only this here in specific, but ANY). This time, the connection is a legitimate one, but next time, it could not (or could be one I simply don't like).

I found this problem while viewing Sysinternals' TCPView. Then, I confirmed it by using Process Explorer, (TCP/IP tab) of each processes.
But neither applications is capable of showing the startup command of these processes... their actual trigger... the **very source** of their launching

I did not find any task on the Task Scheduler

--
A complication I didn't think at first would matter: it's **Windows 7**. Not my computer.

Comment: Adobe products are nowadays under the subscription model, rather than activate once and that's it. It makes sense that if you keep those products installed then it must check for activation at regular intervals.

Comment: Thanks. You probably solved the *Why* part. Now the *How* I believe to be more tricky...

Comment: There's really no "how" the way you want it. If you manage to stop those processes then your Adobe software won't work.

Comment: Don't mind at all. I have to break stuff to learn what happens sometimes. **The objective here is the connection in general.** I imagine that's even the backdoor malwares use to do their "job"

Comment: Check task scheduler (control panel>admin tools) to see it is running from there. If it is disable the task. Also check C:\Windows\Tasks to see if adobe has a task in there, if so delete it.

Comment: Nop. I should've mentioned that I did search on the taks scheduler. Unless there is a search function, I didn't find anything adobe. It's hard coded apparently.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can use a tool such as [GlassWire free](https://www.glasswire.com/), or [an alternative](https://alternativeto.net/software/glasswire/), to see exactly which processes are connecting to which sites.

Second, to prevent an application from connecting, create inbound and/or outbound firewall rule to block each executable *capable* of connecting. Though it's [easy to create an individual rule](https://www.howtogeek.com/227093/how-to-block-an-application-from-accessing-the-internet-with-windows-firewall/), it becomes tiresome if there are many potential offenders (e.g., executables with *.exe* extension and libraries, *.dll*). Use a third-party tool such as free [Folder Firewall Blocker](https://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/folder_firewall_blocker.html) or Sordum's [Firewall App Blocker](https://www.sordum.org/8125/firewall-app-blocker-fab-v1-9/) to automate the process.

Finally, *uninstall unwanted apps*, particularly trial-ware that came with a new PC. Likely, Adobe and other subscription-based products will eventuallu stop working, if internet access is blocked, anyway.

Comment: Good. Part 1 is covered: I listed all the processes attempting communication. Problem is, these processes 1: Are system processes (blocking them causes overall issues). 2: They are very persistent after blocking, therefore, consume CPU. 3: They are a victim here (they are commanded by other process). Uninstalling the software that trigger these connections is not an option, since... I need that software... Notice that my objective is to find the very source of the connection. There's probably a directive **commanding** these system processes

Comment: If they're system process, could be you don't need 'em or want 'em. For example, Windows will show news and weather on various screens, Edge is sending *all* URL's to Bing (https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2023/04/on-by-default-edge-feature-seems-to-be-sending-all-the-urls-you-visit-to-bing/), etc. If you are not already using a privacy tool such as ShutUp10 (https://www.oo-software.com/en/shutup10) or an alternative, see if one can reduce network chatter.